# NEXTJS - TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'X' of '(0 , f.e)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have spend hours and hours figuring out whats going on without any help. In development everything works find but when i try to build my NextJS project im getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'validateToken' of '(0 , f.e)(...)' as it is undefined.
Validate token is a function using inside my Context, here is how it looks like:

```
const userContext = createContext();
export const useUser = () => useContext(userContext);

const UserContext = ({ children }) => {
...
privded={
x,y,z
}
return (
    <userContext.Provider value={provided}>{children}</userContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default UserContext;
```

and im wrapping all components with the contexts provider in the root layout as the following:

```
const RootLayout = ({ children, params }) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/logo192.png" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <ModalContext>
          <UserContext>
            <DataContext>
              <ScreensTemplates>{children}</ScreensTemplates>
            </DataContext>
          </UserContext>
        </ModalContext>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};
```

I would appreciate a tip,
Thanks!

I have tried adding "use client" on the layout itself.
i have tried using dynamic on ScreenTemplates as the following:

```
const ScreenTemplate = dynamic(() => import("@components/ScreenTemplate"), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

without any help, Added Suspense also didnt help.

----------- edited ------------

This is an example how i use my context:

```
const Verification = ({ token, type }) => {
   const { validateToken } = useUser();

   const handleVerification = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const status = await validateToken(token);
      setStatus(status);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleVerification();
  }, []);
...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you use the `validateToken` function?